# schema.org: Qual usar: microdata ou JSON-LD?

Tags: json

A marcação de dados estruturados [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) para os buscadores Google, Yahoo!, Bing e Yandex é ótimo para *rich snippets*. Entretanto percebi que a maioria dos *webmasters* usam microdata e quase nunca usam [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/). Conheci recentemente o JSON-LD e tenho algumas dúvidas que não achei pesquisando:

1. Posso usa-lo sem problema de compatibilidade com todos os buscadores?
2. Posso usar o atributo `src=""` ?

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?

Answer (score 1):

[Respondi algo parecido em 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43960968/287948), mas vou tentar refinar um pouco por aqui.

Antes alguns lembretes importantes:

- [Microdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_(HTML)) é uma extensão do HTML para marcar o conteúdo. Imaginar, para efeito prático, como algo que "passa o mouse em cima e descobre a semântica do fragmento".
- JSON-LD em geral será usado para a "ficha catalográfica" nesse tipo de aplicação HTML, exceto se amarrar muito bem os identificadores de cada parte do conteúdo.

... Imaginar que um robô da Web Semântica, como por ex. o [search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fokfn-brasil.github.io%2Flexml-dou%2Fdemo%2Fprop2_01.html), transforma qualquer página HTML em uma "ficha catalográfica" (FICHA) descritora da página:

- A marcação Microdata pode ser perfeitamente traduzida em JSON-LD, em   RDFa ou RDF. 
  Imaginar que transformando a marcação toda em simples FICHA, será a mesma FICHA, independente da linguagem.
  PS: a definição formal de Microdata foi criada junto com essa tradução (vide *"Converting Microdata to other formats"* na nova proposta [W3.org/TR/microdata](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#converting-html-to-other-formats)).
- Microdata é menos expressivo que RDFa ou JSON-LD.
   Ou seja, existe FICHA  complexa que só pode ser expressa com JSON-LD (vide *"Microdata and RDF"* na nova proposta [W3.org/TR/microdata](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#microdata-and-rdf)).

NOTA:  não há impedimento técnico ou dicotomia, você **pode usar JSON-LD e Microdata juntos** na mesma página. 
Imagine o HTML de sua autoria apresentando a resenha de um artista, com o `<body>` já marcado com    Microdata por exemplo de [WebPage](https://schema.org/WebPage) e propriedades `copyrightHolder` (você) e `genre` (resenha); aí acrescenta no `<head>` ou `<body>` o `<script type="application/ld+json">` com o JSON-LD de Person, descrevendo o artista.

### Cabeçalhos repetitivos de contextualização

[Preferir JSON-LD]

Se o site quer padronizar em todas as suas páginas, propriedades gerais tais como permissões, autoria, etc. é muito mais simples e prático acrescentar o JSON-LD em todas elas.  Wordpress e centenas de outras ferramentas adoram fazer isso, justamente porque é feito meio que "às cegas", ou com base em metadados que eventualmente nem estão presentes no conteúdo HTML, mas o CMS (*content manager system*) tem acesso e pode gerar automaticamente — por ex. ferramentas de SQL tais como [PostgreSQL geram JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) a partir de dados relacionais.

PS: se nunca teve muito contato com isso e deseja gerar "na mão", existem ferramentas que ajudam, tipicamente "JSON-LD generators", como [este](https://hallanalysis.com/json-ld-generator/) ou [este outro](https://www.schemaapp.com/tools/jsonld-schema-generator/). Ex. se a página é sobre uma pessoa, descreva-a com *Person* com informações públicas básicas.

### Marcação semântica mais séria

[Preferir Microdata]

Quando se pretende de fato destacar a semântica de figuras, blocos de texto, etc. como que resumindo para o leitor do que se trata aquele conteúdo, o ideal e mais utilizado é a marcação direta sobre o conteúdo, ou seja, Microdata.

PS: tecnicamente podemos referenciar IDs no JSON-LD, mas ter o conteúdo marcado explicitamente ainda é considerado mais confiável do que referenciar IDs. Ferramentas como [dbpedia-spotlight](https://www.dbpedia-spotlight.org) ajudam a fazer a marcação ao longo do texto.

### Transparência

[Preferir Microdata]

Por exemplo num contrato ou numa matéria de  Diário Oficial, para marcar elementos de identificação, é imprescindível que aquilo que o humano lê é também aquilo que a máquina vai interpretar. [Neste caso por exemplo](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fokfn-brasil.github.io%2Flexml-dou%2Fdemo%2Fprop2_01.html) (ou [neste outro](https://okfn-brasil.github.io/lexml-dou/demo/prop2_02.html)) garantimos que todos os metadados exigidos pelo [padrão LexML](http://projeto.lexml.gov.br/documentacao/Parte-2-LexML-URN.pdf) sejam exatamente os mesmos que o leitor humano está auditando ao ler o documento.

### Regra geral: na dúvida...

- Dúvida meramente técnica sobre qual tecnologia usar, [o Google e os fissurados por SEO sugerem **JSON-LD**](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)
- Se a dúvida do tipo "o que devo descrever?" aí o melhor é usar Microdata, pois a semântica vai emergindo da sua marcação feita sobre o conteúdo. Se expressar com Microdata é mais simples e existem bons editores.